# Как получить объект com.mysql.jdbc.Driver(), если подключаешь Connector/J через Maven?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Подключаю `Connector/J` через `Maven` для дальнейшей работы с `MySQL`:

```xml
<dependency>
     <groupId>mysql</groupId>
     <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
     <version>8.0.25</version>
</dependency>
```

Необходимо произвести регистрацию драйвера с помощью статического метода `DriverManager.registerDriver()`, который в качестве параметра принимает объект типа `Driver`. Как создать этот объект типа `Driver`?

Если бы я [скачивал][1] отдельную `jar`, то регистрировал был так:

```java
DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
```

Имя драйвера берется из `property` файла, следовательно там могут быть различные драйверы, для `MySql`, для `MsSQL`. Есть ли способ, кроме такого, как:

```java
String driverName = // get from property file

if(driverName.equals(com.mysql.jdbc.Driver()) {
    DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
} else if(driverName.equals(other_driver)) {
    DriverManager.registerDriver(new other_driver);
}


  [1]: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-installing.html
```

Comment: Все правильно вы сделали, просто убедитесь что maven подтянул зависимость, можно пересобрать проект.

Comment: @IharHulevich, вот так регистрировать `DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На самом деле у меня работает даже без явной регистрации драйвера (java11)

```
  public static void main(String[] args)  throws Exception{
  //      DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver());
  Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/so", "root", "");
  Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM so.person");
  while (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println(rs.getInt(1) + "  " + rs.getString(2));
  }
  con.close();
```

}